# error LNK2001 - VS2008 & Qt build

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, lnk2001

I'm trying to rebuild a VS2008 project I've got from someone, but I can't figure what's the problem.

the project has dependencies on Boost 1_43 and on Qt-4.6.2 (I've build boost lib and it seems okay with that one).

I've already solved the firsts issues about libs's path and all, by adding the include in the properties of my project. (the path of source files have been added in the C++/General setting, and the path of lib files, added in the Linker/General setting).

But now I'm in front of a ton of LNK2001 errors about Qt objects, and I'm not able to find the problem alone.

any idea ? maybe there is something missing in my Qt insatll ?

Comment: You definitely need to link against Qt libraries too. Add them to the project's settings `Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: why do I have to specify the Qt .lib explicitely in the Additional Dependencies if the path of the .lib is already in Additional Library Directories ?

Anyway, if I had the qtcore4.lib in the additional dependencies, I have another error (LNK1112 module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' - but I'm going to search for that one, I may have not the proper version of Qt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vahancho is right, I needed to link against Qt libraries too, in Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies

My other error was due to Qt 32bit version, and a 64bit compilation.